# How to make only selected posts appear on a selected wordpress page

Tags: plugins, posts, themes, pages

Ok, so this is my [website](http://thelolinternet.com/). I want only selected posts appear on  [one this](http://thelolinternet.com/collection/) page. As you can see, "collection" page have no left side bar and it got 2 columns for posts, unlike other pages (If you are not online from mobile). So i want only selected post to appear in the collection page instead of every (which i post on homepage). How is it possible? Plugin or what?

Please let me know, if you did not understood something.

Answer (score -1):

How you gonna select the posts?
The page "Collection" is displaying only recent posts? All posts? Did you customize it or is the theme's default?

In one site I manage I use the plugin [Display Posts Shortocode](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/) to list posts only of determined tag.

I another site I customized the query and appearance of the posts based on [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-show-recent-posts-by-category-in-wordpress/).

Comment: Yes by Tag sir..

Comment: I added '[display-posts tag="article, Chat"]' this in my page. But it is still displaying all posts.

Comment: If this a plugin problem you should report here: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/display-posts-shortcode